# Gtk-ERROR **: failed to add UI: Error on line 1 char 1: Document must begin with an element

Tags: rust, gtk, glade, gtk-rs

Why is GTK+ 3 throwing this error?

```
(.:11977): Gtk-ERROR **: 21:10:01.149: failed to add UI: Errore alla riga 1 carattere 1: Il documento deve iniziare con un elemento (es. <book>)
```

Translated from Italian to English:

```
(.:11977): Gtk-ERROR **: 21:10:01.149: failed to add UI: Error on line 1 char 1: Document must begin with an element (e.g. <book>)
```

The error says that Rust is trying to open a file (made with Glade) which is empty or its syntax is wrong.

My Rust file compiles without any errors:

```
extern crate gtk;

use gtk::traits::*;
use gtk::Builder;
use gtk::Inhibit;

fn main() {
    // Initialise gtk components
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        println!("Unable to load GTK.");
        return;
    }

    // Load glade file
    let builder = Builder::new_from_string("mainWindow.glade");

    // Create Window
    let window: gtk::Window = builder.get_object("mainWindow").unwrap();

    // Set close event
    window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
        gtk::main_quit();
        Inhibit(true)
    });

    // Show the window and call the main() loop of gtk
    window.show_all();
    gtk::main();
}
```

([Rust file](https://hastebin.com/afudixuzey.php))

The Glade file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
    <!-- interface-css-provider-path style.css -->
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="mainWindow">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="window_position">center</property>
        <property name="default_width">500</property>
        <property name="default_height">350</property>
        <child type="titlebar">
            <object class="GtkHeaderBar">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="title" translatable="yes">rustup-gui</property>
                <property name="subtitle" translatable="yes">A simple GUI for rustup.</property>
                <property name="show_close_button">True</property>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkMenuBar">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Here you can find some basic action which can be done with rustup.</property>
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Rustup</property>
                                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                                <child type="submenu">
                                    <object class="GtkMenu">
                                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                        <child>
                                            <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                                <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Get all the info related to the current rustup installation.</property>
                                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Info</property>
                                                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                                            </object>
                                        </child>
                                    </object>
                                </child>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Set...</property>
                                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                                <child type="submenu">
                                    <object class="GtkMenu">
                                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                        <child>
                                            <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Default toolchain</property>
                                                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                                            </object>
                                        </child>
                                    </object>
                                </child>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                    </object>
                </child>
            </object>
        </child>
        <child>
            <object class="GtkBox">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkBox">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkCheckButton">
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Vervose output (-v)</property>
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="receives_default">False</property>
                                <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
                                <signal name="toggled" handler="tglVerbose_Toggled" swapped="no"/>
                            </object>
                            <packing>
                                <property name="expand">False</property>
                                <property name="fill">True</property>
                                <property name="position">0</property>
                            </packing>
                        </child>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkLabel">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                <property name="margin_left">5</property>
                                <property name="margin_right">5</property>
                                <property name="margin_top">5</property>
                                <property name="margin_bottom">5</property>
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Custom command</property>
                            </object>
                            <packing>
                                <property name="expand">False</property>
                                <property name="fill">True</property>
                                <property name="position">1</property>
                            </packing>
                        </child>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkEntry">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="margin_left">5</property>
                                <property name="margin_right">5</property>
                                <property name="margin_top">5</property>
                                <property name="margin_bottom">5</property>
                                <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">rustup ...</property>
                            </object>
                            <packing>
                                <property name="expand">True</property>
                                <property name="fill">True</property>
                                <property name="position">2</property>
                            </packing>
                        </child>
                    </object>
                    <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">0</property>
                    </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkFrame">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="margin_left">5</property>
                        <property name="margin_right">5</property>
                        <property name="margin_top">5</property>
                        <property name="margin_bottom">5</property>
                        <property name="label_xalign">0.5</property>
                        <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkAlignment">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                <child>
                                    <object class="GtkTextView" id="txtOutput">
                                        <property name="width_request">100</property>
                                        <property name="height_request">130</property>
                                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                                        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                        <property name="margin_left">5</property>
                                        <property name="margin_right">5</property>
                                        <property name="margin_top">5</property>
                                        <property name="margin_bottom">5</property>
                                        <property name="hexpand">True</property>
                                        <property name="vexpand">True</property>
                                        <property name="editable">False</property>
                                        <property name="monospace">True</property>
                                    </object>
                                </child>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                        <child type="label">
                            <object class="GtkLabel">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Console output</property>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                    </object>
                    <packing>
                        <property name="expand">True</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                    </packing>
                </child>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

([Glade file](https://hastebin.com/imavuvurah.xml))

I tried to search for this error, but seems like nobody except me has experienced this awkward error. Maybe it is related to my OS? I'm using Pop!_OS, a Linux distribution based on Ubuntu, made by System76.

Comment: Sounds like you've forgotten to save your file, forgotten to put it in the right place, are loading from a directory you don't expect, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `gtk::Builder::new_from_string()` expects a string with the *full XML* content, not the name of a file. You are passing `"mainWindow.glade"`, that is not valid XML syntax, so you get an error (at line 1, because you only wrote one line).

What you want is to call:

```
Builder::new_from_file("mainWindow.glade")
```

**PS**: A nice feature of the Rust compiler is that you can include files as literal strings, so you can write:

```
Builder::new_from_string(include_str!("mainWindow.glade"))
```

and you will compile the content of the file into the program.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I really don't know how I couldn't see it... Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As I got a same this problem when trying edit GUI xml file on visual studio 2017 or text editors, and put GUI xml files to run it.

Method to fix it:

1. Design your GUI by glade, and save (GtkBuilder file format recommended) as you need.
2. Replace your file name as you have saved in 1.

   2.1 c#,  new_from_file("your file name")

   2.1 c++, gtk_builder_add_from_file(...., "your file name", ....)
3. you are so happy !